# How to upload large files on Streamlit using st.file_uploader

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to upload a binary file of size 10gb using `st.file_uploader`, however, I get the following error message. In fact, I get the same error message pretty much when I am trying to upload any file above 2gb, i.e I didn’t get this error message when I uploaded 1.2gb file.

I have set my file capacity to 10gb in config file.

As a matter of fact, the file loading shows as it should, then the file appears to be uploaded for a very short time (maybe a second), however, then the attachment disappears along with file_uploader widget itself, and the following message pops up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, upload files are limited to 200MB.  You can configure the `server.maxUploadSize` config option as such;

- Set the config option in `.streamlit/config.toml`:

  ```
    [server]
    maxUploadSize=10000
  ```

Comment: Hi @Tony, in fact I have changed the config file and increased the size limit to 40gb. I am able to upload files up to around 2gb, but not larger files.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5938

The bug is raised in Streamlit repo. To be fixed.